# Set Android immersive full screen mode in manifest

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

In the new KitKat there is immersive full screen mode that can be used like this:

> To provide your app with a layout that fills the entire screen, the
>   new SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE flag for setSystemUiVisibility() (when
>   combined with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) enables a new immersive
>   full-screen mode.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI

I'm wondering if it is possible to set this mode for an Activity or full application in the manifest?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to declare immersive mode in the manifest or [window flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html).

It's only available via the view-level [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE) flags, which indicates that it is a request, not a mandate - and that it is a temporary mode.

The system may choose to ignore the request or exit immersive mode at any time, your app should handle those cases.

It's also worth pointing out that hiding the primary navigation on a mobile device is not something to be taken lightly.  It's not appropriate for all apps, and should not be done without thought.

Comment: +1 for your last line as this can easily be misused.